# Filtering out lists and only keeping integers in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to take a list with a mix of integers and strings, filter out the strings in the list, and only keep the integers. An example of a list I might have to filter:

```
filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])
```

Here is my code:

```
new_list = list()
def filter_list(l):
    for step in l:
        if type(l[step]) == int:
            new_list.append(int(l[step]))
        else:
            pass
    return new_list
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(filter_list([1,2,'a','b']),[1,2])
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 4, in filter_list
    if type(l[step]) is int:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong? The traceback is coming from running the test file which tests to see if my code works, but the actual error is from my code.

Comment: `for step in l:` iterates over the elements of `l`, presenting each one in turn in `step`. You don't need to index into `l` to get the element - you have it in `step` already. This is very much how Python loops should be done if possible. (if you *also* need the index, check the [`enumerate` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop in python iterates over the elements, not the indices, of an iterable object. That means that `step` takes on the values `1`, `2`, `'a'`, `'b'`, not 0, 1, 2, 3. In other languages, this sort of iteration is sometimes called `foreach`.

While the first two list elements are valid indices, the last two are not. Also, `l[2]` is `'a'`, which is not an integer. The most basic fix is to fix your indexing. The example below also initializes the new list inside the function, since you probably don't want to keep appending to the same global list (run the function twice to see what I mean).

```
def filter_list(l):
    new_list = []
    for item in l:
        if type(item) == int:
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list
```

You can also make your check of integerness more idiomatic. If you only want to keep objects that are already integers, use `isinstance(item, int)` rather than `type(item) == int`. If you want to allow things like the string `'123'` to pass through, use `int(item)` in a try-except instead:

```
def filter_list(l):
    new_list = []
    for item in l:
        try:
            new_list.append(int(item))
        except TypeError, ValueError:
            pass
    return new_list
```

The most idiomatic way to express the version with a conditional is to use a list comprehension:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [item for item in l if isinstance(item, int)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To restate what I grasped from this; I was getting this type error because the loop was stepping through the actual values of the list, rather than the "list positions" of those list values, and getting caught up when it reached a string. Also, using try-except is a more pythonic way of solving an algorithm like this. Thanks again!

Comment: @AidenManansala. You got it. The try-except allows strings with numbers through, `isinstance` does not. Both are quite pythonic depending on what you want to do. Checking `type(x)==int` (or slightly better `type(x) is int` are less pythonic, but again, it all depends on the exact use-case in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Other people already provided solutions, but they didn't explain, why your didn't work.

Your list is [1,2,'a','b']. Python throws exception at element 'a'. If you run this code:

```
list = [1,2,'a','b']
for step in list:
   print(step)
```

Your output would be:

```
1
2
a
b
```

As you can see 3rd element of your list is string - that's why you get

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

To get index of element use enumerate:

```
list = [1,2,'a','b']
for index, value in enumarate(list):
   print(f"{index}: {value}")
```

Output:

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: a
3: b
```

Your code with enumarate:

```
new_list = list()
def filter_list(l):
    for step, value in enumarate(l):
        if type(l[step]) == int:
            new_list.append(int(l[step]))
        else:
            pass
    return new_list
```

Comment: I believe that my answer already did cover that

Comment: Yes, sorry. You didn't post yours when I started writting. I was referring to other people answers - they only provided solution.

Comment: Irritating, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```py
list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), [1,2,'a','b']))
```

Python's built in `filter` function has two arguments, first one is a function that you want to apply the filter with and the second one is the object being filtered.

output:

```py
[1, 2]
```

Comment: The question was "what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm following the guidelines! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  . Try this instead!

Comment: That's a very selective reading of the paragraph. A question saying "what am I doing wrong?" has a valid answer.